# The Java Scanner is not taking my String Input

Tags: java, string, input, java.util.scanner

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = scan.nextInt();
    double d = scan.nextDouble();
    String s = scan.nextLine();
    

    System.out.println("String: " + s);
    System.out.println("Double: " + d);
    System.out.println("Int: " + i);
}
```

Here is my code. It is compiled properly and no syntax error but I can't understand why my String input is not taken. As soon as I give the integer input and the double input, the output is coming as:

**INPUT**

42

309.23

**OUTPUT**

String:

Double: 309.23

Int: 42

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`scan.nextDouble()` or `scan.nextInt()` doesn't finish the line so when `scan.nextLine()` comes simple you can say that it consume the leftover blank line so the String prints nothing. To consume the leftover line put `scan.nextLine()` before `String s = scan.nextLine();`

Answer (score 2):

Note that for the single line input `1 1.1 done` you shall get the output:

```
String:  done
Double: 1.1
Int: 1
```

That `done` is preceded in the output by a space character hints to you that scanner is consuming one token at a time. Checkout for example the documentation for [scan.nextInt](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextInt()) and [scan.nextLine](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine())